# firebase-php error: Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read my firebase database' data using the [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) library.

I'm initializing the library using this script, the X's are placeholders, obviously.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
define('DEFAULT_URL', 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com');
define('DEFAULT_TOKEN', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('DEFAULT_PATH', '/firebase/orders');

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);
```

But I'm getting an error running $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH);

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   index.php on line 76

Since $firebase is null there is obviously going something wrong during initializing, but I can't seem to find what causes this.

Comment: This is not the complete code, can you add all of the relevant code?

Comment: I've quickly browsed the source code and it doesn't seem to use exceptions. Instead there`s `trigger_error()` all around. Have you enabled the appropriate error reporting directives?

Comment: @Robert Then what am I missing..? I'm trying to initialize the firebase class and then do a function call, according to the examples in the readme that's all you need to do.

Comment: @Yumeeh are you calling `$firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH);` directly below the creation of the `$firebase` object? Do you call it in a function? or a class? The context of where you actually call the line of code that causes the error is missing from your code.